# JQuery Chosen and JQuery Validate - set Color on invalid Selectbox

Tags: jquery, validation, select, jquery-chosen

i use the Plugin Chosen for my selectbox and validate() for the validation of my form. The Selectbox is also required.

I would change the color of my Selectbox if it is not valid. I have found the validation option "errorClass" for my fields. it works fine for my input and textarea but not for the "Chosen-selectbox". Because the class is in the hidden selectbox not on the "Chosen-selectbox".

Have you any ideas how i can do this?

Thank You!

Comment: i have use css-siblings. so it works.
select.NameOfErrorClass + div.chosen-container{ color:red}

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
});
```